# Socket Communication on UWP (Universal Windows Platform)

Tags: c#, sockets, uwp

What I want to implement is UWP-based programs and other C# programs are trying to communicate with Socket on one PC (Windows 10 Pro).

I have tried to make UDP communication module using DatagramSocket class and TCP communication module using StreamSocket class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/windows/uwp/networking/sockets) and it seems that module is not working properly.

In the Windows UWP example program and some developer forums, I saw a statement that it is impossible that socket communication between other programs on the same device.

I am wondering if it was the right I understood.

Also, if it is right, Would you recommend other ways to solve this problem?

Comment: `I saw a statement that it is impossible that socket communication between other programs on the same device.` I think that's nonsense...

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Thank you for reply. I agree that it is nonsenese.

Comment: I always use the default `Socket` for tcp communication.

Comment: How can I use the default Socket on UWP?

Comment: If you are going to use streams you could use the [StreamSocket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocket.aspx)

Comment: Plus you'll have to enable the Client and/or Server network [capabilitiy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations) of the App ind it's 'package.manifeat'

Comment: Thank you for reply. I  also try the StreamSocket class but still it doesn't work. Of course, I edit the package.manifeat

Comment: What means doesn't work. Which c# project you are trying to community with uwp? Who is the server, who is the client? What you actually need to work , StreamSocket or DatgramSocket?

Comment: c# program is server and uwp program is client on same machine. When  uwp program uses the StreamSocket class and c# program uses TcpListener class, c# program can't receive the package from the uwp program. Also when  uwp program uses the DatgramSocket class and c# program uses Socket class(SocketType.Dgram), it doen't work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I saw a statement that it is impossible that socket communication between other programs on the same device

It is right. According to the note of [DatagramSocket official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DatagramSocket):

> Network communications using an IP loopback address cannot normally be used for interprocess communication between a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app and a different process (a different UWP app or a desktop app) because this is restricted by network isolation.

We cannot communicate a uwp app with other apps in a same machine.

> Also, if it is right, Would you recommend other ways to solve this problem?

By testing on my side, if you use a c# console project as server and a uwp app as client, they can communicate successfully both with `StreamSocket` and `DatagGramSocket`. But following special steps need to pay attention to let it work.

- Please ensure the Internet(Client&Server) and Private Internet(Client&Server)   [capabilities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations) are enabled.
- Run the server side as administrator.
- Allow the network access promoted by windows when you run the server.

  [image]

I wrote a demo which contains server side and client side of UDP and TCP. You can download [here](https://github.com/sunteenwu/Sockets/tree/master/ServerClient) for testing.

And the results.

[image]

Although this can work, I recommend you to not use except for developing purpose.